# Getting value from a subscription again and again in angular

Tags: angular

Scenario: On clicking a button, it consumes an api and returns the value. Then after a minute, again call the same api and returns the value. But I don't want to unsubscribe and subscribe it again. Is there any other way to achieve it?

My Code:

```
 getStatus() {
    this.isActive = true;
    this.apicall$ = interval(1 * 60 * 1000)
      .pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.service.checkStatus(this.movieForm.value.movie))
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        const response: any = res;
        if (!response.status) {
          this.movieStatus = {
            movie: this.movieForm.value.movie,
            status: response.status,
            message: 'Booking not yet opened!'
          };
        } else {
          this.movieStatus = {
            movie: this.movieForm.value.movie,
            status: response.status,
            message: 'Booking opened!'
          };
          this.playAudio();
          this.apicall$.unsubscribe();
        }
      });
  }
```

I'm getting the value again and again but the problem i'm facing with this code is, When I click the button, it waits for 1 minute and then consumes the api. I need some other clean way to fix this issue.

i don't know whether it helps or not, but I have deployed the code [here](https://varanjith.com/#/spicinemas). Select a movie and click start. You can notice in the network tab (inspect), there won't be any calls, but after 10 mins(i set it up as 10 mins in deployed version) first call will be consumed !

**UPDATE #1:**

You can see the whole code [here](https://github.com/darthranjith/OneApp/tree/master/projects/spicinemas-lib/src/lib/components/spicinemas)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { interval, Subscription, Subject, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { flatMap, merge, startWith, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  clickTrigger = new Subject<boolean>();

  clickObservable$: Observable<boolean>;
  sub: Subscription;
  ngOnInit() {
    let fakeBackend = of({ data: "fake" }).pipe(delay(300));
    this.clickObservable$ = this.clickTrigger.asObservable();
    this.sub = interval(5 * 1000)
      .pipe(
        merge(this.clickObservable$),
        flatMap(() => fakeBackend)
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("polling", data);
      });
  }

  poll() {
    console.log("poll click");
    this.clickTrigger.next(true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You can use `merge` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) for that. You create a subject use it as an observable then merge it with your original observable. Then on button click fire the subject with calling `.next()` function in order to trigger an emit. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wr9gf) sample. Check the console.